# How to generate a cv::Mat type code?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been using the c-style api to generate opencv type codes. For example:

```
cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC2);
```

CV_8UC2 is a macro defined in types_c.h (deprecated?):

```
#define CV_MAKETYPE(depth,cn) (CV_MAT_DEPTH(depth) + (((cn)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))
```

Is there a similar type code generation function in the c++ api, something like

```
Mat m(w,h, cv::Type(Vec<unsigned char, 2>).typecode()) ?
```

Comment: When you say "the C-style API"... are you referring to the macros? Aren't macros part of C++? :)

Comment: Also: in OpenCV 3.0, `CV_MAKETYPE` is defined at `core/cvdefs.h`, which is clearly not deprecated.

Comment: What do you want me to call it? The cv1 and cv2 APIs?

Comment: What I meant is that `CV_MAKETYPE` is still part of OpenCV, it's not like `IplImage` or any of the deprecated `cvWhatever` functions...

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comments, `CV_MAKETYPE` is not deprecated, and afaik it is the standard way of generating those "type codes".

However (**and just for fun**), an alternative, more C++-ish, way of generating arbitrary codes (still in compile time) can be achieved by using [TMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Template_metaprogramming)...

```
template <int depth,
          int cn>
struct make_type
{
    enum {
       // (yes, it is exactly the same expression used by CV_MAKETYPE)
       value = ((depth) & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK) + (((cn)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT)
    };
};

// You can check that it works exactly the same as good, old `CV_MAKETYPE`     
cout << make_type<CV_8U,2>::value << " "<< CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,2) << endl;
```

... but don't do this. While tmp is fun and amazing, `CV_MAKETYPE` is the right way of doing things in this case.

EDIT: OpenCV has its own type traits utilities. In `core/traits.hpp` we can find class `DataType`:

> The DataType class is basically used to provide a description of ...
> primitive data types without adding any fields or methods to the
> corresponding classes (and it is actually impossible to add anything
> to primitive C/C++ data types). This technique is known in C++ as
> class traits. It is not DataType itself that is used but its
> specialized versions
> ...
> The main purpose of this class is to convert compilation-time type
> information to an OpenCV-compatible data type identifier
> ...
>
> So, such
> traits are used to tell OpenCV which data type you are working with,
> even if such a type is not native to OpenCV.

Comment: It's good to know this is still the standard. What about cv::DataType in core.hpp though? I see a cursory CV_MAKETYPE(depth, channels) in it (opencv rc1). How can you generate a type with it? I think whether using one or the other is better, is a different (and normative) question.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Seems that a trait- based version of basic type stuff already exists in OpenCV. I'll update my answer. Nevertheless, I think the standard way of doing what you wanted to do is still `CV_MAKETYPE`